# Streamlit displaying multiple dataframes for each row

Tags: python, pandas, arduino, streamlit

I am trying to display my data from an Arduino Uno on a Streamlit app. I am using the following Python code, which creates a serial connection to the Arduino, a Streamlit app, and reads data from the Arduino continuously by updating a Pandas dataframe. However, the code is producing multiple data frames instead of appending new rows to the existing data frame. How can I modify this code to ensure that all the values are added to a single data frame after every iteration of the loop?

````py
import serial
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Create a serial connection to Arduino
arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)  # Replace 'COMX' with the appropriate port

# Create Streamlit app
st.title('Arduino Data Table')

data = {'Current': [], 'Temperature 1': [], 'Temperature 2': [], 'Total Voltage': [], 'Maximum Voltage': [],
        'Minimum Voltage': [], 'Cell 1': [], 'Cell 2': [], 'Cell 3': [], 'Cell 4': [], 'Cell 5': [], 'Cell 6': [],
        'Cell 7': [], 'Cell 8': [], 'Cell 9': [], 'Cell 10': [], 'Cell 11': [], 'Cell 12': [], 'Cell 13': [],
        'State of Charge': []}

p_list = ['Current', 'Temperature 1', 'Temperature 2', 'Total Voltage', 'Maximum Voltage', 'Minimum Voltage', 'Cell 1',
          'Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4', 'Cell 5', 'Cell 6', 'Cell 7', 'Cell 8', 'Cell 9', 'Cell 10', 'Cell 11', 'Cell 12',
          'Cell 13', 'State of Charge']

# Continuously read data from Arduino and update the DataFrame
def show_data():
    while True:
        for i in range(len(p_list)):
            line = arduino.readline().decode().strip()  # Read a line from Arduino
            palak = line.split(':')[1]
            palak = palak.split()
            p = float(palak[0])
            data[p_list[i]].append(p)
        final_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        st.write(final_data)  # Display the updated DataFrame

def main():
    show_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```[here is output which is not in a single dataframe][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esY3N.png
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly because you are creating `final_data` inside the `while true`.
I couldn't test the code since it probably need Arduino input. I believe that you need to create the DataFrame outside the loop and concatenate your data inside the loop.
For instance,

```
# Continuously read data from Arduino and update the DataFrame
def show_data():
    # I am creating the DataFrame outside the Loop HERE
    final_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=p_list)
    while True:
        for i in range(len(p_list)):
            line = arduino.readline().decode().strip() # Read a line from Arduino
            palak = line.split(':')
            palak = palak.split()
            p = float(palak)
            data[p_list[i]].append(p)
        # and HERE, I am appending new rows to final_data DataFrame
        final_data = pd.concat([final_data, pd.DataFrame(data)], ignore_index=True)
        st.write(final_data) # Display the updated DataFrame
```

I hope this helps!